# On connectivity of Lie subgroups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Here we assume that all manifolds are second-countable.

Let $ G $ be a Lie group and $ H $ be its Lie subgroup. That is, $ H $ is a subgroup of $ G $ equipped with a differential structure with which $ H $ is a Lie group and the inclusion map $ \iota\colon H \to G $ is an immersion. Let $ H' $ denote $ H $ as a topological subspace of $ G $. Note that the topology of $ H $ is generally different from that of $ H' $.

I am thinking about the relationship between the following four conditions:

1. $ H $ is connected;
2. $ H $ is path-connected;
3. $ H' $ is connected;
4. $ H' $ is path-connected.

Here is what I understood:

- 1 and 2 are equivalent since $ H $ is a manifold.
- 1 (or, equivalently, 2) implies 3 and 4 since a continuous image of a connected (resp. path-connected) is connected (resp. path-connected).
- 3 does not imply 1. To see this, let $ G = \mathbb{T}^2 = \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2 $ and
  $$ H = \{(x, \sqrt{2} x) + \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{(x + 1/2, \sqrt{2} x) + \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}. $$
  Then $ H $ is a Lie subgroup of $ G $ which is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $, but $ H' \subseteq G $ is connected.
- 4 implies 3 (generality from General Topology), but the converse is not true as the above example shows.

Now my question is:

> Does 4 imply 1? That is, if the subspace $ H' \subseteq G $ is path-connected, is the Lie group $ H $ (path-)connected?

**Remark.** Without second-countability, there are trivial counterexamples such as $ (\mathbb{R}, \text{discrete}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \text{usual}) $.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between definitions of $H$ and $H'$. can you give an example?

Comment: @C.F.G For $ G $ and $ H $ given in “3 does not imply 1” in the question, $ H $ and $ H' $ are not homeomorphic. $ H $ (equipped with its own differential structure) is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $ as a Lie group, so it is not connected. Meanwhile, $ H' $ is connected as a topological subspace of $ G $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 4 does imply 1.

The key observation is that every Lie subgroup $H\subseteq G$ is an integral manifold of an involutive distribution (see Theorem 19.25 in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, 2nd ed.), which implies that a continuous map into $G$ whose image lies in $H$ is actually continuous as a map into $H$. (This is proved in exactly the same way as Theorem 19.17 in *ISM*. That proof assumed the map was smooth, but the same proof goes through with "smooth" replaced by "continuous" throughout.)

To prove 4 $\implies$ 1, suppose $H\subseteq G$ is a Lie subgroup and $H'$ is path-connected. Given any two points $p,q\in H$, there is a continuous path $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to H'$ with $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(1)=q$. Then $\gamma$ is continuous as a map into $G$ by composition with the inclusion map $H'\hookrightarrow G$, and therefore it's continuous as a map into $H$ by the observation in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I followed Theorem 19.17 in your book and understood that the proof works in continuous case under the assumption that the domain is locally connected: Let $ X $ be a locally connected space and $ f\colon X \to H $ is a map which is continuous into $ G $. For $ x \in X $, we can take a flat chart $ V $ around $ f(x) \subseteq G $ and a connected neibourhood $ U \subseteq f^{-1}(V) $ of $ x $. Since $ H \cap V $ is contained in at most countable slices of $ V $, $ f(U) $ is contained in a single slice. This proves that $ f|_U\colon U \to H $ is continuous.